# How to create an image that changes state?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, image

What is the best way to create an HTML image that displays various states (e.g. for a button: normal, hovered, selected, disabled)?
Ideally, I want to do via CSS classes (including the `:hover` meta-class).

Also, I've seen multiple states combined into a single image (which makes image pre-loading easier), but I don't know how to display a single slice of the image as needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Excuse me, but what exactly do you mean by the term "HTML image", because I guess, the trivial solution using the "background" attribute of CSS for different styles is not what are you looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about CSS Sprites. Here's a A List Apart article to get you started: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites. The basic idea is that you have all of your images combined into a single, large image.

Whereas normally you will have `img` tags or small elements with background image applied, now you have the single image applied to multiple elements as a background image, and each of them have different background position values to position the correct image into position. An example of this would be jQuery UI's icons - the single combined image look like this:

[image]

Then each of the individual icons share a single class, with a `backgroun-image` set:

```
.ui-icon{width:16px;height:16px;background-image:url(../images/ui-icons_808080_256x240.png);}
```

As well as individual `background-position` for each of the different icons:

```
.ui-icon-carat-1-n{background-position:0 0;}
.ui-icon-carat-1-ne{background-position:-16px 0;}
.ui-icon-carat-1-e{background-position:-32px 0;}
.ui-icon-carat-1-se{background-position:-48px 0;}
```

The same can be done for the individual interactive states - change the background-position of the element on `:hover`, and you get a different color or icon.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out: http://josefaeti.com/tutorials/css/css-how-to-use-multiple-images-stored-in-a-single-file.html#box-0

and this: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites